# Magento 1.7 / How to delete "This is a required field" when start typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototype

I want to hide (remove) the message "This is a required field" from the product option text field when user starts typing into it.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("product-custom-option").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("advice-required-entry-select_"+this.id).remove();
};
```

But it does not work.

Comment: you need to used another event.

Comment: Please define "But it does not work" more explicitly

Answer (score 0):

use onfocus, onblur, onkeypress for text fields instead of onclick

Answer (score 0):

You can set is required no from admin for that product. or you just remove required entry class from that custom option field

Answer (score 0):

```
function req(option_id) {
var e = document.getElementById("select_"+option_id);
var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
if(selectedValue == '-- Please Select --') {
    document.getElementById("select_"+option_id).className = "required-entry product-custom-option validation-failed";
    if(document.getElementById("advice-required-entry-select_"+option_id)) {
        if(document.getElementById("advice-required-entry-select_"+option_id).style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById("advice-required-entry-select_"+option_id).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
if(selectedValue && selectedValue !== '-- Please Select --') {
    document.getElementById("select_"+option_id).className = "required-entry product-custom-option";
    //document.getElementById("advice-required-entry-select_"+option_id).remove();
    if(document.getElementById("advice-required-entry-select_"+option_id)) {
        document.getElementById("advice-required-entry-select_"+option_id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

}